# Analyse how frequent a table in sql server is used by any query

Tags: sql-server

I was assigned to delete tables and indexes in a database which are used less frequently. Is there any tool or something that would say how many times a table has been queried ? And also is it possible to say the usage of an index. I just want to delete the index that are not used frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx). It contains all the information about when was the last time the index was seeked, scaned, looked up or updated. But keep in mind that the data is reset at every database startup *and* it may be reset under memory pressure. In other words, is not 100% reliable. In addition, there can always be workloads that are critical but run seldom, like monthly reports, that need certain indexes.

Comment: Your caveat is especially important. You have to understand the schema, the queries, the jobs the database runs to do this task, not just blindly delete tables and indexes based on some query.